# How to call SQL functions in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have recently been working on database project, including SQL. I have written a simple function in SQL Server that counts the sum of some one of the columns.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Count_kontrakty_sum](@id_z INT)
    RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(Kontrakty.wysokosc)
            FROM Kontrakty
            WHERE id_zawodnika = @id_z)
END
```

When called as a database query, it works perfectly

```
PRINT dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum(66);
```

But when I want to call it from my Python program it gets a bit different.

I have tried a lot of different formats of calling this func, but every time I get some error:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('{CALL Count_kontrakty_sum?}', 60)
record = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLPrepare)')

```
cursor.execute('exec dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum?', 66)
```

results in:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum@P1'. (2812) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Is there another way to call SQL function in pyodbc ?

Comment: Why didn't you include the parens?  `'exec dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum(?)'`?

Comment: cursor.execute('exec dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum(?)',66)  gives:pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: I tried different versions of these 2 methods but noone of them work

Comment: I have now, I posted the other one. Sorry

Comment: @eatmeimadanish -- The `@P1` is how the SQL Server connector does parameter substitution.

Comment: Oh, I see one other thing.  The substitution list needs to be a tuple: `cursor.execute('exec dbo.Count_kontrakty_sum(?)', (60,))`.

Comment: Try `cursor.execute("SELECT Count_kontrakty_sum(?) AS n", 60)`